# iOS using one general UIView as newsScroller in every ViewController, or any View

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I tried to find answer for this question, but i couldnt find.

I'm developing an application what's using tabBarController as main navigation, and there are also navigationControllers in every Tab.

I would like to make a little 30px height news-scroller view under the navigationBar on every screen, but this scroller should be application-level, because it should show the same text on every view, and should change the text in the same time. I dont think that making 9 scrollerView and connect them somehow isnt the best way.

Is there any woraround for this in iOS?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: so do u want to put ur tab bar inside ur scroler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way would be to subclass a UIViewController and add scrollView in top of the view (bellow the navigationBar). After that connect the scrollView instance with single (app wide) scrollView data model instance for example with KVO or Notifications technique. This approuch should fit to MVC pattern.

Comment: So i will have a scrollView instance everyhere, where i need it, but it will show data from an application-level data model sure?

Comment: Yes, you would have only one data model object which will hold data and manages updates.

Comment: Ok then i have got 1 more question. I want a timer to push data into the scroller in every X seconds. Can i reach the instances to push them to change? Thank you.

Comment: You can send from data model a notification every x second or update key value every x second and KVO will manage it. Also from scroll view you can access data using singelton or accessing from appDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

May be you add your ticker into the main view

Comment: The problem is there is no main View. I have got a tabBarController, and tabs added to it. Every tab is a NavigationController. I dont really have a "main view"

Comment: And also if i add it to window in appdelegate. It wont animate with navigationController for example. It will be fixed there.

Comment: as you know when each tab view activate - deactivate, its' possible to manage some animation on a "global" view

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be possible to subclass the tabBarController in order to hold your scrollview as a subview?
Simply speaking in term of architecture it would do the trick. But it could not be as easy to perform as I think. (I am not an interface friend)